# passing a link with parameter to the redirection link after a php authorization

Tags: php, html, validation, parameters

I'm sorry if the title is really not clear.
What I want to do is very simple just I'm not a php expert and I don't know where to start from.

I've used FORM-GUIDE php code to validate my users.
At the moment I have the following code at the top of the page that needs validation:

```
<?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");

if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("PLAY.php");
   }
}
```

Now what I need to do is to give a link with the  "v_id" variable to my user.
Just for instance my users will receive the following link:

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/PLAY.php?v_id=item01
```

and I would like after they've validated to redirect to correct page using:

```
$fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("PLAY.php?v_id=item01");
```

So to redirect to the correct location using the v_id variable in this case is item01 but it could be item02 and so on.

Where should I start from to make it possible?

THANK YOU SO MUCH IN ADVANCE!!!

Davide

Comment: Well, we don't know what the function ```RedirectToURL``` is doing so it's hard to guess

Comment: Excuse me!!! it's part of the FORM-GUIDE!   it's the following function:                          function RedirectToURL($url)
    {
        header("Location: $url");
        exit;
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am i right that you don't know how to pass a parameter into `RedirectToURL` function?
if that so, you should try:

```
if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $param = 'item'.$id; //here you should set parameter with some $id (01,02, etc) dynamically
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("PLAY.php?v_id=$param"); //pass it into function
   }
```

after that you're redirect on page with form, where you need to set right **action** with parameter `<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(). "?v_id=$param"?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>`
where $param is `$param = $_GET['v_id'];`

Comment: This helped me to understand how to pass a value to a variable. THANK YOU!!! Now I need to understand how to solve my problem.
I've tried to explain it better below. Please let me know if you know how to help me!!!

Comment: If you are in page `http://www.mywebsite.com/PLAY.php?v_id=Blue_see`
you can get `Blue_see` like that:
`$param = $_GET['v_id'];`
So you get that parameter from URL and you can use it to pass to another function.

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was doing but it's not working!!! Consider this is the code: <?PHP  require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");
$param = $_GET['v_id'];
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{
//echo $param;
   if($fgmembersite->Login())
   {
        $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("PLAY.php?v_id=$param");
   }
}

?>If I use echo before isset I can see it's working and it's keeping the variable content If I use echo after isset echo return nothing so there is something there which is deleting the variable content. Any idea?

Comment: I've just got it!!! The problem is that I'm submitting a form with the following settings:<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'> and I've seen it's possible to pass the variable content here but I don't know how it works in this case because I need to use $fgmembersite validation protocol included in form-guide!  I hope someone will be able to suggest a solution here. Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: you are submitting form `<form id='login' action='<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>`

`$fgmembersite->GetSelfScript();` is a current page, according to https://github.com/simfatic/RegistrationForm/blob/master/source/include/fg_membersite.php#L289

If you want to add some parameter do it like this:
`<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript() . "?param=$parameter" ?>`

Comment: THANK YOU THAT WORKED!!!!!!!! to be much precise, just in case any other user would like to understand it,  it is:<?php echo $fgmembersite->GetSelfScript() . "?v_id=$param" ?>

Comment: If my answers helped you to solve the problem, then you can "accept" it to help other users to find right solution.
https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Answer (score 0):

If I am right you are lookin for this:

```
 if($fgmembersite->Login())
  {
    $param = 'item'.$id;
    $fgmembersite->header("PLAY.php?v_id=$param"); 
 }
```

And then you need to get the value of v_id in PLAY.php,so PLAY.php should  have this code:

```
if(isset($_GET['v_id']){
$val=$_GET['v_id'];}
```

Now do something with the value.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Where exactly should I put                                                if(isset($_GET['v_id']){
$val=$_GET['v_id'];}                                                                                        in Play.php ? The php part is the following:                                                    <?PHP
require_once("./include/membersite_config.php");


if(!$fgmembersite->CheckLogin())
{



    $fgmembersite->RedirectToURL("Restr_Area.php");
    exit;
}
?>

Comment: As it is the main part of your code that extracts the item no,you should put it at the top or below the "require_once" line of code.And then you can check the item with if else and do something with it.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['v_id']){
$val=$_GET['v_id'];}                                                                                         This is not working and prevent the page to open.  Please read my latest post below. I've tried to explain my problem better.